# App on release crashes, while on debug doesn't

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, ormlite, release-mode

I'm developing an app using Android Studio, and when I switched from **debug** to **release** build variant, it began to crash. While on debug it doesn't happen anything at all. The real problem is that I can't find where is the true error, as every reference is renamed.

Have you faced an error like this, that has happened only on **release**?

The printed stack is this:

```
04-11 08:28:42.756    5997-5997/com.korcholis.clothio E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to inflate
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1906)
            at android.support.v7.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.n.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.g.setContentView(Unknown Source)
            at com.korcholis.clothio.SampleListActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5303)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find constructor that hast just a (Context) argument for helper class class com.korcholis.clothio.b.c
            at com.a.a.a.a.a.c(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.a.a.a.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.korcholis.clothio.fragments.SampleListFragment.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.i(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.ae.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.ae.b(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.ae.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.w.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1906)
            at android.support.v7.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.n.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.g.setContentView(Unknown Source)
            at com.korcholis.clothio.SampleListActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5303)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:397)
            at com.a.a.a.a.a.c(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.a.a.a.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.korcholis.clothio.fragments.SampleListFragment.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.i(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.ae.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.ae.b(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.ae.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.w.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1906)
            at android.support.v7.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.n.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.g.setContentView(Unknown Source)
            at com.korcholis.clothio.SampleListActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5303)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 08:28:42.756    5997-5997/com.korcholis.clothio D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-11 08:28:42.756    5997-5997/com.korcholis.clothio W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41902700)
04-11 08:28:42.756    5997-5997/com.korcholis.clothio E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.korcholis.clothio/com.korcholis.clothio.SampleListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5303)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1906)
            at android.support.v7.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.n.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.g.setContentView(Unknown Source)
            at com.korcholis.clothio.SampleListActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5303)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find constructor that hast just a (Context) argument for helper class class com.korcholis.clothio.b.c
            at com.a.a.a.a.a.c(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.a.a.a.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.korcholis.clothio.fragments.SampleListFragment.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.i(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.ae.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.ae.b(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.ae.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.w.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1906)
            at android.support.v7.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.n.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.g.setContentView(Unknown Source)
            at com.korcholis.clothio.SampleListActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5303)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:397)
            at com.a.a.a.a.a.c(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.a.a.a.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.a.a.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.korcholis.clothio.fragments.SampleListFragment.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.i(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.ae.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.ae.b(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.ae.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.w.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1906)
            at android.support.v7.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.n.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v7.a.g.setContentView(Unknown Source)
            at com.korcholis.clothio.SampleListActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5207)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1272)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5303)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you guys

EDIT: So as AesSedai101 stated, it was a matter between Proguard and something I am using: Ormlite. So I'll add the tag and a proguard file that worked to me:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class com.korcholis.clothio.data.** {     *; }
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
```

Replace `com.korcholis.clothio.data.**` with the package where you store your database models, but don't forget the final `.**`

Comment: Post your `SampleListFragment` code.

Comment: before signing your app remove all lint error.you will find it using- Right Click on Project->Android Tools -> Run lint.Ckeck for common errors

Comment: @SimplePlan It is quite long, here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/Korcholis/10444650

Comment: @yuvaツ Ok, I'll check for those errors, but how can it be that it just breaks in release mode?

Comment: I think you got problem because of wrong `Context`.

Comment: Using lint error you will find errors.remove that error

Comment: Do you use proguard for the release?

Comment: @Henry I do, that's why the methods have silly names as a, b or c. But even after disabling it, the error was there with the same signatures (weird, I have to dig that a little more)

Comment: i am getting the same error, how did to fixed the error? i mean how to configure the proguard in release? -Korcholis

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Looks like Proguard is removing a constructor from one of your classes. Be sure to add the Proguard config as specified in the [manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html). If this is not added, Proguard will remove all unused code, which includes things like Activity constructors.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks, let me accept your answer as valid

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem and running Build > Clean Project before generating a new signed APK fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The similar issue I also found and mentioned about it in:

https://medium.com/@aanshul16/android-app-crashes-in-release-mode-but-working-perfectly-in-debug-c051cc83a019

You can check first just by enabling minifyEnable to true in your debug flavour, if issue get reproduced then definitely it is because of proguard.